# How to get all the old and new Values without specifying explicitly giving column names?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table with some values. I wrote a trigger on that table as follows.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER display_changes 
After DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON users 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.ID > 0) 
BEGIN 
  dbms_output.put_line('Old values: ' || :OLD.id); 
  dbms_output.put_line('New values: ' || :NEW.id);
  --  column2
  dbms_output.put_line('Old values: ' || :OLD.name); 
  dbms_output.put_line('New values: ' || :NEW.name);
   -- column3
  dbms_output.put_line('Old values: ' || :OLD.address); 
  dbms_output.put_line('New values: ' || :NEW.address);
   -- for all columns 
END;
```

So what I'm asking, Is there any better way to do it? Like using * operator with `:OLD` and `:NEW` variable. Or something better approach without specifying all the columns ?

thanks.

Comment: Please edit your *tags* and delete what is not applicable. I doubt that the question is about both MySQL and about Oracle. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask what you want to do with it ? And what is the problem in mentioning the columns explicitly ?

Comment: Unless `users` is an object table, your only option is to explicitly specify each column that you want to reference.  Depending on what the actual problem is, you can write code that dynamically generates the actual trigger code but that adds additional complexity.